# Transferring a specific app from one Android device to another

Tags: applications

I use an application called time card for Android every time I switch to a new phone I never seem to be able to transfer that app and the data on it which is extremely important to me can anyone help me figure out how to do this as I need to send the old device back as it was a warranty situation

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do a full backup of that app, i.e. including its data. That usually requires root, but there are some solutions for this specific case to make it work without root – see [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](/q/28296/16575). The two candidates you should look at:

- `adb backup -f <appname>.backup -apk <package_name>`
- Helium Backup (an app which does this on-device, but will need to be initialized via ADB)

Basically, there's no way around [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) for this. For details, see the linked question with its answers, and our [adb tag-wiki](/tags/adb/info).

**Note:** As [Death Mask Salesman](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/152843/death-mask-salesman) correctly pointed out, apps can opt out of ADB backups (developers can include a flag in their apps' Manifests advising the system to *not* permit ADB to back it up). So if your app falls into that category: bad luck without root.

Comment: Helium had no say in that. The ADB daemon would refuse. Thanks for pointing this out, I've just integrated it with my answer (credits given).

Answer (score -2):

All your Apps are collected in your account at play store just sign in and 
you will be able to download it to any device.

Comment: How does this help with restoring the app's **data**?